# How to read the zipfile in chunks using multipart formdata in golang

Tags: file, go, multipartform-data, multipartfile

I am trying to read the zip file in chunks. The scenario is, I am uploading the large file through our endpoint and trying to read that zip file in smaller chunks. I have been following this code but it throws as error stating that not a valid zip file.

```
package main

import (
    "archive/zip"
    "bytes"
    "io"
    "log"
    "mime/multipart"
    "net/http"
    "os"

    "github.com/labstack/echo/v4"
)

func main() {
    e := echo.New()

    // Route to handle file uploads
    e.POST("/upload", uploadHandler)

    // Start the server
    e.Logger.Fatal(e.Start(":8080"))
}

func uploadHandler(c echo.Context) error {
    // Read the form data including the file
    form, err := c.MultipartForm()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Get the file from form data
    fileHeaders := form.File["zipFile"]
    if len(fileHeaders) == 0 {
        return c.String(http.StatusBadRequest, "No file uploaded")
    }

    // Open the uploaded file
    file, err := fileHeaders[0].Open()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer file.Close()

    // Create a new zip file to write the extracted contents
    outFile, err := os.Create("extracted.zip")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer outFile.Close()

    // Create a zip writer for the output file
    zipWriter := zip.NewWriter(outFile)
    defer zipWriter.Close()

    // Accumulate chunks of data until we have a complete zip file
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    _, err := io.CopyN(&buf, file, 8192) // Read 8KB chunks
        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                break
            }
            return err
        }

        // Create a zip reader for the current chunk of data
        zipReader, err := zip.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(buf.Bytes()), int64(buf.Len()))
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        // Iterate over each file in the zip file
        for _, f := range zipReader.File {
            // Open the file in the zip archive
            rc, err := f.Open()
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            defer rc.Close()

            // Create a new file in the output zip
            outFile, err := zipWriter.Create(f.Name)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }

            // Copy the file contents to the output zip
            _, err = io.Copy(outFile, rc)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
        }

    // Return success response
    return c.String(http.StatusOK, "Files extracted and written to extracted.zip")
}
```

This below code block throwing the error:

```
// Create a zip reader for the current chunk of data
   zipReader, err := zip.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(buf.Bytes()), int64(buf.Len()))
  if err != nil {
     return err
  }
```

The intention of this code is reading the zip file into smaller chunks and write it into another zip file.

Comment: You don't have to extract and recompress the the zip file in order transfer the bytes, just copy the stream. A zip file can't be extracted until you read the entire thing, because the [central directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)#Central_directory_file_header) is at the end of the archive.

Comment: What would be best way to read the large zip files and write them in memory? If the file size is huge, server will take the lot of times read the zip file in a single request. To avoid this I had planned to read this in chunks.
Any suggestion? @JimB

Comment: Just copy the bytes to a new file, you don't need to interpret the format of those bytes in any any way.

Comment: You mean complete copy of huge file.
Using io.Copy(dest, src), is that right?

Comment: yes, you use `io.Copy` to copy a stream of bytes.

Comment: If you want to save the file to your local host machine, then `io.Copy`. If you are saving to an alternative, like S3, then you can utilize a passthrough stream to not take up your memory allocation or local storage.